# convert function from using two `let` and `in` to use only one `let`

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I found this type `zipper` and `insert` functions defined like this:

```
type 'a zipper = 'a list * int;;

exception Empty

let empty = ([], 0)

let insert ((l, n): 'a zipper) (a: 'a) : 'a zipper =
  let rec ins ll nn =
    if nn = 0 then a::ll 
    else 
      match ll with
      | [] -> raise Empty 
      | h::q -> h::(ins q (nn-1))
  in 
  (ins l n, n)
```

How can I convert this function to use only one `let` and without that `in (ins l n, n)`

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the number of local function definitions is mostly a non-sensical metric, but you can certainly do it

```
let cons x (l,n) = (x::l,n+1)
let rec insert (l, n) a =
  if n = 0 then a::l,n
  else
    match l with
    | [] -> raise Empty 
    | h::q -> cons h (insert (q,n-1) a)
```

Comment: I really like this solution, better if you could ve done tail-recursive

Answer (score 1):

Writing an insert function that uses `n` in the `zipper` value and returns a list is trivial.

```
# let rec insert' ((l, n) : 'a zipper) v =
    if n = 0 then v :: l
    else 
      match l with 
      | [] -> raise Empty
      | x::xs -> x :: insert' (xs, n - 1) v;;
val insert' : 'a zipper -> 'a -> 'a list = <fun>
# insert' ([1;2;3;4;5], 5) 6;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

This is essentially what your inner function is doing.

The trick is when you need to return a `zipper` value with that original `n` value. The `ins` function of `insert'` function I've shown above update that value on each iteration, and each iteration doesn't know anything about the previous ones, so we can't get the original value of `n` back.

That's why your original solution with the inner function works. The inner function can generate the updated list, and then wrap it in a tuple with the original value of `n`.

Are there ways to do this without the local binding? Well, below is one, but it isn't especially efficient.

```
let insert (l, n) v =
  if List.length l <= n || n < 0 then raise Empty; 
  (l |> List.to_seq |> Seq.take n |> List.of_seq)
  @ [v]
  @ (l |> List.to_seq |> Seq.drop n |> List.of_seq)
```

Comment: ? Without a tail-recursiveness constraint, it is trivial to get rid of the inner recursive function.

Comment: I see, what if we want to build a tail-recursive one and we add another argument?